# Samsung S Duos GT-S7562

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My galaxy s dous s7562 is getting switched off when Internet is on and sometimes is phone is also getting switched off even when the battery is around 50%. When the Phone is restarted the battery level shows 1%. I am not able to get connected with Wifi & Share it app with other phones.What is the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Might be your battery got corrupted or Expired, Have you tried replacing your battery, And do not post multiple questions within one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your battery is older and needs replacement. Have you tried using apps like [BetterBatteryStats](http://www.appbrain.com/app/betterbatterystats/com.asksven.betterbatterystats)? But they would just give you the stats and some more insights.

If possible try with some other battery.